# Ext JS Combobox inside button menu doesn't keep focus

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I recently deal with a focus problem when I'm typing in a combobox (which is in a button menu) and that my mouse is moving out of the field, then I loose the focus on it and cannot type anymore.
This does not come from the combobox itself because if I create one on the window it works well.
I'm using Ext js 4.1.3 and I'm wondering if there is a workaround or an alternative to create such component.
some code :

```
Ext.define('xxxxx.SaveOptionsButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button'
    ,alias : 'widget.saveOptionsButton'
    ,constructor : function(config) {
        var me = this;  
        me.menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', 
            {   
                showSeparator:false
                ,frame:true
                ,items: [
                   {
                        xtype: 'checkboxgroup'
                        ,items: [
                            {
                                xtype:'checkbox'
                                ,name:'save'
                                ,checked: true
                            }
                            ,
                            {
                                xtype:'combo'
                                ,name: 'myComboName'
                                ,queryMode:'local'
                             }
                         ]
                 }]
         });
   }
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it adding :

```
,listeners: {
     mouseover : function (menu, item, e, eOpts) {
     //fix bug of loosing focus on combo


     menu.down("combo[name=shipmentTemplates2]").focus();
         }
}
```